# I wrote the script below to elaborate error

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Example{
  public static void main(String []args) throws FileNotFoundException ,IOException {
       File file = new File("/home/pal/Documents/java/Song Storage/songs.txt");
       FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("./songs.txt",true);
       String s = "tata";
       char ch[] = s.toCharArray();
       for(int i=0 ;i < s.lenght() ;i++){
             fout.write(ch[i]);
       }
      fout.close();
  
  }
}
```

---

```
Error: Example.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
       for(int i=0 ;i < s.lenght() ;i++)
                         ^
       symbol:   method lenght()
       location: variable s of type String
       1 error
```

Comment: Its a typo. `"lenght".equals("length") == false`

Comment: `lenght` should be `length`. You may use an IDE, like intellij, or Eclipse, it'll you the methods that exists on an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lenght()  shold be length()

```
for(int i=0 ;i < s.length() ;i++){
             fout.write(ch[i]);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's length
Not lenght
Your spelling is wrong